# Dynamically display razor page based on a certain condition

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, razorengine, razorgenerator

I am looking to dynamically display a razor page based on some condition. Specifically, I intend to have a parent page model and have that dynamically invoke a child page model based on some condition. My current folder structure looks like this

- Parent

  - Child a
  - Child b
  - Child c

So depending on the condition, Child a or Child b or Child c should be invoked and it's corresponding page should be displayed to the user. I thought about overriding the parent's `OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync`, however I'm not quite sure how that can be achieved as I'm quite new to .Net Core.

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean about child page in razor page? As far as I know, there is no child page in razor page. Do you use partial page in razor page? Besides, you should tell us based on which condition to redirect to each page.

Comment: By child page, I meant if there's anyway to dynamically invoke a page within it's parent. I intend to use the parent as a wrapper, then decide on which page to view when the parent page is hit. I know this is possible with ViewComponents by you cannot achieve full encapsulation with it as posting goes through the parent. I wanted to know if this is possible